# How to "separate" writing from reading in a serial bus (Arduino)?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, delay

I'm doing an applications that `writes in` and `reads from`an Arduino (Uno). The way that I want Arduino works is read ONLY when data is available (like a listener) and writes every time (periodically using `delay`). But I don't know how to setup a listener (or if there is a way to do it), because I dont want the `delay` to influence the `reading`.

```
 unsigned long timeDelay = 100;   //Some configurations
 String comand;
 char received;
 const int LED = 12;

void setup() {
  //start serial connection
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);   //LED is only a way that I know the Arduino is 
  digitalWrite(LED,LOW);  //reading correctly

}

void loop() {
  //How to separate this part--------------Reading from Serieal--------
  comand = "";
  while(Serial.available() > 0){    
    received = Serial.read();
    comand += received;
    if(comand == "DELAY"){            //Processing the command
      timeDelay = Serial.parseInt();
    }
  }
  if(comand == "Desliga"){            //Processing the command
     digitalWrite(LED,LOW);       //'Desliga' means 'turn on' in portuguese
  }
  else if(comand == "Liga"){          //Processing the command
    digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);       //'Liga' means 'turn off' in portuguese
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------

  //From this other part-----------------Writing on Serial-------------
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  Serial.flush();
  delay(timeDelay);        // delay in between reads for stability
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

OBS: I'm doing a connection thru a Java application. So I can set the `timeDelay` there. If I put a `timeDelay` like `1000`(ms), than one command that I wrote (to turn on/off the `LED`) will take 1 second to be processed.
Did you guys get it?

Anybody has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a task manager for Arduino to run your analog code.

I use [`TaskAction`](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/TaskAction) for this.

You can wrap your analog code in a function and create a `TaskAction` object:

```
void AnalogTaskFunction(TaskAction * pThisTask)
{
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  Serial.flush();
}

static TaskAction AnalogTask(AnalogTaskFunction, 100, INFINITE_TICKS);
```

and in your `loop`, you can run the task and also set the task period:

```
void loop() {
  //How to separate this part--------------Reading from Serieal--------
  comand = "";
  while(Serial.available() > 0){    
    received = Serial.read();
    comand += received;
    if(comand == "DELAY"){            //Processing the command
      AnalogTask.SetInterval(Serial.parseInt()); // Change the task interval
    }
  }
  if(comand == "Desliga"){            //Processing the command
     digitalWrite(LED,LOW);       //'Desliga' means 'turn on' in portuguese
  }
  else if(comand == "Liga"){          //Processing the command
    digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);       //'Liga' means 'turn off' in portuguese
  }

  AnalogTask.tick(); // Run the task
}
```

Note: other task managers for Arduino are available, this is just the one I'm familiar with. You may want to explore others.